# actions-on-google implicit flow and access_token change?

Tags: access-token, implicit-flow

I have developed a Google Action for Assistant (with `Api.ai`). I have to use a Sign-in method because my app use a website where the user have to sign-in and make something.

In the action console I setup account linking with `IMPLICIT` method and under `AUTHORIZATION URL` I inserted my url for the login. It's works.

When I speak for the first time (for testing) to my Google Home, on my smartphone appears the notification for account linking... perfect. My website create a token and record it and every time after my webhook will call with the same access_token. Perfect.

Two questions

1. This access_token is linked to my google-account forever or google may change it?
2. How can I disable this account-linking and reset my google-action? I want to re-link my assistant with new access_token. I try to return a http 401 from my webhook but it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

1. The access token is just a piece of string so Google cannot change that exact one. It might have a lifetime.
2. I am pretty sure Google has an endpoint that revokes the access token.